# lables do not display properly using Raphaël

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display an analytics chart using Raphaël like the one found at:
http://joedesigns.com/labs/Beautiful-Analytics-Chart/#download

Everything works except the label, it does not follow the data path properly...the label data is showing up randomly in the top left corner of the graph and the frame that is supposed to contain the label data shows up on one data point only, not traversing along the points with your cursor.  I believe the error is in the analytics.js file but I'm not sure what I need to change.

Here is what I have for the analytics.js file:

```
            var gridHasBeenDrawn=false;
    Raphael.fn.drawGrid=function(x,y,w,h,wv,hv,color){color=color||"#cacaca";
    var path=["M",Math.round(x)+.5,Math.round(y)+.5,"L",Math.round(x+w)+.5,Math.round(y)+.5,Math.round(x+w)+.5,Math.round(y+h)+.5,Math.round(x)+.5,Math.round(y+h)+.5,Math.round(x)+.5,Math.round(y)+.5],rowHeight=h/hv,columnWidth=w/wv;for(var i=1;i<hv;i++){path=path.concat(["M",Math.round(x)+.5,Math.round(y+i*rowHeight)+.5,"H",Math.round(x+w)+.5]);}
        for(i=1;i<wv;i++)
        {
            path=path.concat(["M",Math.round(x+i*columnWidth)+.5,Math.round(y)+.5,"V",Math.round(y+h)+.5]);
        }
    return this.path(path.join(",")).attr({stroke:color});};
    function getAnchors(p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y,p3x,p3y){var l1=(p2x-p1x)/2,l2=(p3x-p2x)/2,a=Math.atan((p2x-p1x)/Math.abs(p2y-p1y)),b=Math.atan((p3x-p2x)/Math.abs(p2y-p3y));
        a=p1y<p2y?Math.PI-a:a;b=p3y<p2y?Math.PI-b:b;var alpha=Math.PI/2-((a+b)%(Math.PI*2))/2,dx1=l1*Math.sin(alpha+a),dy1=l1*Math.cos(alpha+a),dx2=l2*Math.sin(alpha+b),dy2=l2*Math.cos(alpha+b);
        return{x1:p2x-dx1,y1:p2y+dy1,x2:p2x+dx2,y2:p2y+dy2};}
    function drawLine(conf){var holder=!conf.holder?'':conf.holder,data_holder=!conf.data_holder?'':conf.data_holder,mastercolor=!conf.mastercolor?'#01A8F0':conf.mastercolor,spewidth=!conf.spewidth?500:conf.spewidth,showarea=!conf.showarea?false:conf.showarea,linecolor1=!conf.linecolor1?'#000000':conf.linecolor1,linecolor2=!conf.linecolor2?conf.mastercolor:conf.linecolor2,mousecoords=!conf.mousecoords?'rect':conf.mousecoords,nogrid=!conf.nogrid?false:conf.nogrid;
    var labels=[],data=[],datatotal=[],lines1=[],lines2=[];
        if(!$(data_holder))
        {
            return false;
        }
    $$("#"+data_holder+" tfoot th").each(function(s){labels.push(s.innerHTML);});$$("#"+data_holder+" tbody.data td").each(function(s){data.push(s.innerHTML);});$$("#"+data_holder+" tbody.line1 td").each(function(s){lines1.push(s.innerHTML);});$$("#"+data_holder+" tbody.line2 td").each(function(s){lines2.push(s.innerHTML);});
    var width=spewidth,height=250,leftgutter=0,bottomgutter=50,topgutter=20,colorhue=.6||Math.random(),color=mastercolor,r=holder,txt={font:'10px Helvetica, Arial',fill:"#000000"},txt1={font:'bold 11px Helvetica, Arial',fill:"#000000"},txt2={font:'bold 10px Helvetica, Arial',fill:"#000000"},X=(width-leftgutter)/labels.length,max=Math.max.apply(Math,data),Y=(height-bottomgutter-topgutter)/max;if(!r.gridDrawn&&nogrid==false){r.drawGrid(leftgutter+X*.5+.5,topgutter+.5,width-leftgutter-X,height-topgutter-bottomgutter,10,10,"#eaeaea");}
    r.gridDrawn=true;var path=r.path().attr(
    {stroke:color,
    "stroke-width":4,
    "stroke-linejoin":"round"}),bgp=showarea==true?r.path().attr({stroke:"none",opacity:.3,fill:color}):r.path().attr({stroke:"none",opacity:0,fill:color}).hide(),label=r.set(),is_label_visible=false,leave_timer,blanket=r.set();
    label.push(r.text(60,12,"24 hits").attr(txt1));
    label.push(r.text(60,27,"22 September 2008").attr(txt2).attr({fill:color}));
    label.hide();
    var frame=r.popup(100,100,label,"right").attr({fill:"#ffffff",stroke:"#666","stroke-width":2,"fill-opacity":.8}).hide();
    var p,bgpp;
    for(var i=0,ii=labels.length;i<ii;i++)
    {
        var y=Math.round(height-bottomgutter-Y*data[i]),x=Math.round(leftgutter+X*(i+.5)),t=gridHasBeenDrawn[holder]==false?labels.length>120?i%2==0?false:r.text(x,height-25,labels[i]).attr(txt).rotate(70).toBack():r.text(x,height-25,labels[i]).attr(txt).rotate(70).toBack():false;if(!i){p=["M",x,y,"C",x,y];bgpp=["M",leftgutter+X*.5,height-bottomgutter,"L",x,y,"C",x,y];
    }if(i&&i<ii-1)
    {
    var Y0=Math.round(height-bottomgutter-Y*data[i-1]),X0=Math.round(leftgutter+X*(i-.5)),Y2=Math.round(height-bottomgutter-Y*data[i+1]),X2=Math.round(leftgutter+X*(i+1.5));
    var a=getAnchors(X0,Y0,x,y,X2,Y2);
    p=p.concat([a.x1,a.y1,x,y,a.x2,a.y2]);
    bgpp=bgpp.concat([a.x1,a.y1,x,y,a.x2,a.y2]);}
    var dot=r.circle(x,y,4).attr({fill:"#ffffff",stroke:color,"stroke-width":2});
    if(y==0)
    {
        dot.attr({opacity:0});
    }
    if(mousecoords=='circle')
    {
        blanket.push(r.circle(x,y,14).attr({stroke:"none",fill:"#fff",opacity:0}));
    }
    else if(mousecoords=='rect')
    {
        blanket.push(r.rect(leftgutter+X*i,0,X,height-bottomgutter).attr({stroke:"none",fill:"#fff",opacity:0}));
    }
    var rect=blanket[blanket.length-1];
    (function(x,y,data,datatotal,lbl,line1,line2,dot)
    {
        var timer,i=0;rect.hover(function(){clearTimeout(leave_timer);
        var side="right";if(x+frame.getBBox().width>width){side="left";
    }
    var ppp=r.popup(x,y,label,side,1);
    if(mousecoords=='circle')
    {
        frame.attr({path:ppp.path,width:'200px'}).show();
        label[0].attr({text:line1,fill:linecolor1,translation:[ppp.dx,ppp.dy]}).show();
        label[1].attr({text:line2,fill:linecolor2,translation:[ppp.dx,ppp.dy]}).show();
    }else if(mousecoords=='rect')
    {
        frame.show().stop().animate({path:ppp.path},200*is_label_visible);
        label[0].attr({text:line1}).show().stop().animateWith(frame,{translation:[ppp.dx,ppp.dy]},200*is_label_visible);
        label[1].attr({text:line2}).show().stop().animateWith(frame,{translation:[ppp.dx,ppp.dy]},200*is_label_visible);
    }
    frame.toFront();
    label[0].toFront();
    label[1].toFront();
    this.toFront();
    dot.attr("r",6);
    is_label_visible=true;},function(){dot.attr("r",4);
    leave_timer=setTimeout(function(){frame.hide();
    label[0].hide();
    label[1].hide();
    is_label_visible=false;},1);});})(x,y,data[i],datatotal[i],labels[i],lines1[i],lines2[i],dot);}
    gridHasBeenDrawn[holder]=true;
    p=p.concat([x,y,x,y]);
    bgpp=bgpp.concat([x,y,x,y,"L",x,height-bottomgutter,"z"]);
    path.attr({path:p});
    bgp.attr({path:bgpp});
    frame.toFront();
    label[0].toFront();
    label[1].toFront();
    blanket.toFront();}
    (function(){var tokenRegex=/\{([^\}]+)\}/g,objNotationRegex=/(?:(?:^|\.)(.+?)(?=\[|\.|$|\()|\[('|")(.+?)\2\])(\(\))?/g,replacer=function(all,key,obj){var res=obj;key.replace(objNotationRegex,function(all,name,quote,quotedName,isFunc){name=name||quotedName;if(res){if(name in res){res=res[name];}
    typeof res=="function"&&isFunc&&(res=res());}});
    res=(res==null||res==obj?all:res)+"";return res;},fill=function(str,obj){return String(str).replace(tokenRegex,function(all,key){return replacer(all,key,obj);});};
    Raphael.fn.popup=function(X,Y,set,pos,ret){pos=String(pos||"top-middle").split("-");pos[1]=pos[1]||"middle";
    var r=5,bb=set.getBBox(),w=Math.round(bb.width),h=Math.round(bb.height),x=Math.round(bb.x)-r,y=Math.round(bb.y)-r,gap=Math.min(h/2,w/2,10),shapes={top:"M{x},{y}h{w4},{w4},{w4},{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r},{r}v{h4},{h4},{h4},{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,-{r},{r}l-{right},0-{gap},{gap}-{gap}-{gap}-{left},0a{r},{r},0,0,1-{r}-{r}v-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r}-{r}z",bottom:"M{x},{y}l{left},0,{gap}-{gap},{gap},{gap},{right},0a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r},{r}v{h4},{h4},{h4},{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,-{r},{r}h-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1-{r}-{r}v-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r}-{r}z",right:"M{x},{y}h{w4},{w4},{w4},{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r},{r}v{h4},{h4},{h4},{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,-{r},{r}h-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1-{r}-{r}l0-{bottom}-{gap}-{gap},{gap}-{gap},0-{top}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r}-{r}z",left:"M{x},{y}h{w4},{w4},{w4},{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r},{r}l0,{top},{gap},{gap}-{gap},{gap},0,{bottom}a{r},{r},0,0,1,-{r},{r}h-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}-{w4}a{r},{r},0,0,1-{r}-{r}v-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}-{h4}a{r},{r},0,0,1,{r}-{r}z"},offset={hx0:X-(x+r+w-gap*2),hx1:X-(x+r+w/2-gap),hx2:X-(x+r+gap),vhy:Y-(y+r+h+r+gap),"^hy":Y-(y-gap)},mask=[{x:x+r,y:y,w:w,w4:w/4,h4:h/4,right:0,left:w-gap*2,bottom:0,top:h-gap*2,r:r,h:h,gap:gap},{x:x+r,y:y,w:w,w4:w/4,h4:h/4,left:w/2-gap,right:w/2-gap,top:h/2-gap,bottom:h/2-gap,r:r,h:h,gap:gap},{x:x+r,y:y,w:w,w4:w/4,h4:h/4,left:0,right:w-gap*2,top:0,bottom:h-gap*2,r:r,h:h,gap:gap}][pos[1]=="middle"?1:(pos[1]=="top"||pos[1]=="left")*2];var dx=0,dy=0,out=this.path(fill(shapes[pos[0]],mask)).insertBefore(set);switch(pos[0]){case"top":dx=X-(x+r+mask.left+gap);dy=Y-(y+r+h+r+gap);break;case"bottom":dx=X-(x+r+mask.left+gap);dy=Y-(y-gap);break;case"left":dx=X-(x+r+w+r+gap);dy=Y-(y+r+mask.top+gap);break;case"right":dx=X-(x-gap);dy=Y-(y+r+mask.top+gap);break;}
    out.translate(dx,dy);
    if(ret)
    {
        ret=out.attr("path");out.remove();
        return{path:ret,dx:dx,dy:dy};
    }
    set.translate(dx,dy);
    return out;};})();
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `width` and `height` specified should be the same as the `width` and `height` of the `div#holder`. Take a look at the demo here: http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html